# I lost my android app password, what should I do?

Tags: android

I recently misplaced my flash drive with my android apps passwords on it. I now have to make some updates to my android app but I can't because I don't have access to my flash drive which is where my passwords are stored. What should I do? Open to all answers!

Answer (score 2):

Cry?  That's really all you can do.  I had a paid app and I lost my keystore and there was no way to update my app.  I had to change the package identifier, sign it with a new keystore and then upload it as a new app.  This means that I had to refund everyone who purchased the old app and ask them to purchase the new one.  If it's only the password you're missing then I'd say keep trying to guess it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about your keystore passwords, there is absolutely no way to retrieve them. You'll have to find that flash drive, remember your passwords, or start signing your apps with a new keystore (of which you would then have to post any updates of your apps as new applications under a new package name).

If there *was* a way, malicious users would be able to acquire keystore passwords for apps that are not their own, and be able to post updates to them.